# Old C# Winform project I got to work on doesn't have designer.cs to describe the window; rather all in InitializeComponent(). Why?

Tags: c#, winforms

Project was initially made in VS2010 and any changes to the windows form (add a button) it updates the InitializeComponent() function where everything is currently kept to build the window instead of the designer.cs file. What kind of setting would have the person used to make it this way in the past?

Comment: that was before partial classes were introduced in .NET 3.5

Comment: @Nino Looking at the project properties it has a target framework of .net 4 so I don't believe so.

Comment: That doesn't mean the project started in .net 4.

Comment: Create it manually

Comment: There could be many reasons... File deleted, corrupted, incorrect manipulation, lost file (for ex. was not added to source control), manual project editing, moving some files around, file created manually that way... in addition to other points above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scenarios:

1. Project created in before .NET 3.5 era and later upgraded to .NET 4.0 will still be this way.
2. UI handcoded.
3. UI designed in an external tool and finally code copy pasted in to the form's InitializeComponent()